# Draw arbitrary polygons instead of certain characters when painting a String

Tags: java

I need to draw a text line where some specified characters would be replaced by arbitrary polygons. These polygons must be painted with Graphics directly using [drawPolygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29). method. While Unicode contains a range of graphical symbols, they are not appropriate for this task.

I was wondering if it was possible to replace a character with a polygon, in any instance of that character's occurrence in a string?
For example, if I typed-in the word 'Holly' and hit 'enter', the first letter would be replaced by the polygon.
If I then went to type the word 'thistle', the polygon's new position would be in place of the second letter?

Any help/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you asking about changing a character in your UI for a polygon?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain *why* you want to do that - right now it is hard to understand what you are asking...

Comment: I need to replace the character with a polygon I've drawn using the drawPolygon() method.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your are asking

Comment: @Bohemian I need to replace a character in a string with a polygon I've drawn using the drawPolygon() method. =)

Comment: Yes, you said that before, so repeating it doesn't help. I understand each individual word you have said, but when put together they are nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the actual polygon is represented in Unicode all you have to do is string replacement.

```
System.out.println("Hello".replace('H', '\u25C6'));
```

produces

> ◆ello

Comment: Seems reasonable, but what does the "('H', '\u25C6')" bit mean?
I need to replace the character with a polygon I've drawn using the drawPolygon() method.

Comment: `String`s contain bare text.  You can't insert things that aren't characters into them.

Comment: I see. So there isn't a way to display a word/phrase with a specific character displayed as a drawn polygon?

I've also considered somehow changing the polygon's position relative to the char's position in the string, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that or if it would work.

Comment: Either that, or I thought maybe I could wrap the rest of the string around the polygon - but again, that's something I'm not quite sure how to do.

Comment: @ElementOfMagic, the polygon in my example is actually a regular character in the string. Java can display any of the >110'000 [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters. Character `25C6` just happens to be a polygon. This is by far the easiest method to "draw" polygons. If you want anything fancier you need to place your custom polygon _over_ or inside the text as described by Audrius Meškauskas.

Comment: It has to be a specifically shaped polygon that I've drawn with the drawPolygon() method. That polygon must take the place of the letter 'h' or 'H' in a string typed into a textfield by the user, no matter where in the string that letter appears.

Comment: @MarcelStör How would I place my custom polygon over/inside the text?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a polygon, may be the easy way is to choose a Unicode symbol 
There are lots of them with graphic contents (even a snow man)

Comment: I need to replace the character with a polygon I've drawn using the drawPolygon() method.

Answer (score 0):

This is fully doable with [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) that allow to measure the dimensions of the string as printed with the given font. Use FontMetrics to determine to compute the locations of the string fragments and then draw the string fragments and polygons in between.

This approach seems reasonable if the polygons must be somehow very special (maybe non-Unicode characters?), or they required dimensions are very different from the letter dimensions in the used font.

In early days of Java when the Unicode support was yet not very good, it was not uncommon to draw unsupported national characters that way.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to replace the character with a polygon I've drawn using the drawPolygon() method.

Comment: E? This is exactly that I propose!